# Could anyone explain how to save RGB image from kinect on Raspberry Pi using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, computer-vision, kinect

I tried cv.SaveImage function to accomplish it, but I was getting some unexpected error saying that writer not found. Thanks in advance.

**/* This is my sample code */**

```
import freenect    
import cv   
import frame_convert   
import time   
import cv2   
import numpy as np   

cv.NamedWindow('Depth')
cv.NamedWindow('RGB')
keep_running = True

def display_depth(dev, data, timestamp):   
    global keep_running   
    cv.ShowImage('Depth', frame_convert.pretty_depth_cv(data))  
    #time.sleep(1)   
    if cv.WaitKey(10) == 27:  
       keep_running = False   


def display_rgb(dev, data, timestamp):  
    global keep_running  
    cv.Image= frame_convert.video_cv(data)   
    img = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(cv.Image), cv.IPL_DEPTH_16S, 3)   
    cv.ShowImage('RGB',cv.Image)   
    for x in range(1,5):   
     name= "img%d" %(x)   
     cv.SaveImage('name',cv.Image);   
     time.sleep(1)   
    if cv.WaitKey(10) == 27:   
        keep_running = False   

def body(*args):   
    if not keep_running:    
        raise freenect.Kill   

print('Streaming from Kinnect... Please wait...Press ESC in window to stop') 
freenect.runloop(depth=display_depth,
                 video=display_rgb,
                 body=body)
```

Comment: Why are you using `cv` instead of `cv2`? Did you try `cv2.imwrite()`?

Comment: Yes I did try cv2.imwrite( ), it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

## Using cv2.imwrite its very easier. Here I have saved RGB and Depth data as images in .png format but you can change it to whatever you want.

## Hope it Helps.

```
#import the necessary modules

import freenect
import cv2
import numpy as np

#function to get RGB image from kinect
def get_video():
    array,_ = freenect.sync_get_video()
    array = cv2.cvtColor(array,cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    return array

#function to get depth image from kinect
def get_depth():
    array,_ = freenect.sync_get_depth()
    array = array.astype(np.uint8)
    return array

if __name__ == "__main__":
    i = 0
    while 1:
        #get a frame from RGB camera
        frame = get_video()
        #get a frame from depth sensor
        depth = get_depth()
        #display RGB image
        cv2.imshow('RGB image',frame)
        #display depth image
        cv2.imshow('Depth image',depth)
        k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
        if k == 27:         # wait for ESC key to exit
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        elif k == ord('s'): # wait for 's' key to save and exit
            cv2.imwrite('frame'+str(i)+'.png',frame)
            cv2.imwrite('depth'+str(i)+'.png',depth)
            i = i+1
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to change `cv.SaveImage('name',cv.Image);` into `cv.SaveImage('name.jpg',cv.Image);` in the display_rgb method.